# What's a difference between "on" and "when" in the new angular defer block

Tags: angular, syntax, deferred, angular17

New Angular defer block comes with some new features.

We can use *when* element as well as *on* element. What's the difference between them?

```
@defer (when isReady) {
 <span appFoo>
  {{ 'foo' | upperCasePipe }}
 </span>
 }
```

vs

```
@defer (on interaction) {
  <span appFoo>
    {{ 'foo' | upperCasePipe }}
    </span>
} @placeholder {
  <button>Trigger loading!</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`on` is meant to be used with the built-in triggers: `interaction`, `hover`, `immediate`, `idle`, `timer` and `viewport`.

`when` works with component variables/methods.